# Actionscript: Check Throttle Status?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, throttling

Is there a way to check the throttle status without using ThrottleEvent?

E.g., someone else's Flash container swf loads, gets throttled and receives the ThrottleEvent, then loads my swf.  Can my swf tell that it's throttled?

(Assume I do not know the owner of the container swf and cannot change it in any way.)

Comment: I don't know of an easy way without tracking the events (I believe the stage framerate value doesn't actually change).  But, it seems unlikely it would be throttled prior to loading your swf - and once your swf is loaded you can track the events.

Comment: I don't think you can. Why do you want to know?

Comment: Many platforms don't support ThrottleEvent anyway. If you want to know if it's supported just try to create an instance of it with getDefinitionByName and then use a proxy class to handle it if it's available but since not all platform support it don't put much important logic into that.